# AutoMapper and Quartz.Net server - missing type map configuration

Tags: automapper-3, quartz.net-2.0

I'm attempting to use AutoMapper within Jobs hosted by Quartz.Net server.
At service startup, I load all the mapping profiles, one of which has:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Models.ManufacturerAlias, Business.Models.ManufacturerAlias>();
```

In the Job, I call the Map<>, but I get the following error:
Exception: AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
Mapping types:
ManufacturerAlias -> ManufacturerAlias
SmartBIM.Data.Models.ManufacturerAlias -> SmartBIM.Business.Models.ManufacturerAlias
Destination path:
ManufacturerAlias
Source value:
SmartBIM.Data.Models.ManufacturerAlias

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() is not giving me any exceptions.

Is this a threading issue - do I need to load the profiles at the Job.Execute()?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's threading issue. We had the similar. Static methods of AutoMapper are not thread-safe.